# Android In App Billing make a managed product free

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

In my app i have several managed products which have a certain price. In the release week I want to make some of them free of charge. As the minimum price on Google Play Developer console is 0.5€, I'm not sure how to make those products free of charge and at the same time save its SKUs to the Google Play servers (as it happens on default purchase flow). I want that, because a user may delete the app and reinstall it later.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem? I am facing a similar problem. It would be nice to have **free** "switch" products which we can just switch on and off so that states can be permanently stored on the Google server linked to the game.

Comment: Noup, at that time the only solution I found was via code (without going via IAB flow). The other option you have would be to implement your own server-side logic and first check your server for free products (in case you need some non pre-defined periods at which you want to offer free products and not uploading a new apk). I know that Google released a new IAB API and have made some changes to the Developer console in the last year, so maybe they did some work on free products as wel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the price of an in-app product once it is published, and you can't sell an item for free. You will have to implement this yourself, maybe by keeping a record of SKUs that a user has access to that is separate from what Google Play gives you. When a user clicks "buy" for a product, pays for it, and consumes it, then add that SKU to the list. If you want to offer a free product, simply add that SKU to the list as well without going through the IAB flow.

Comment: ah, i was hoping this is not the case, because i don't have my own server... Without server-side i cannot guarantee users to permanently own those items. In case of deleting the app, user won't own it any more (because SharedPrefs and database are deleted as well...). Thanks for answer!

Comment: You can make use of the Backup Service http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html if you want to save data across uninstalls. Not sure how well this syncs across devices though.

Comment: You can use firebase as your server tho'

Answer (score 2):

See [In-app Promotions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html) — Where Developers can create promo codes which users can redeem for content or features.

Promo codes let you give content or features away to a limited number of users free of charge. After you create a promo code, you can distribute it subject to the terms of service. The user enters the promo code in your app or in the Google Play Store app and receives the item at no cost.